# sbox containing tikz gives "missing \endgroup insert"

Tags: tikz-pgf, insbox

This is a minimal working example.  The full problem actually contains a couple of `adhorn` ornaments, but for brevity only a few plots are included here.  The `tikzpicture` by itself compiles

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{adforn}
 
\begin{document}

\newsavebox{\tileone}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
    \clip (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
    \begin{scope}[dashed,blue]
        \draw plot (\x,\x-1);
        \draw plot (\x,\x+1);
        \draw plot (\x,-\x+1);
        \draw plot (\x,-\x+3);
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But when I wrap it in an `\sbox`, the compilation fails and I get a  "`missing \endgroup insert`" error.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{adforn}
 
\begin{document}

\newsavebox{\tileone}
\sbox{\tileone}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
    \clip (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
    \begin{scope}[dashed,blue]
        \draw plot (\x,\x-1);
        \draw plot (\x,\x+1);
        \draw plot (\x,-\x+1);
        \draw plot (\x,-\x+3);
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\usebox{\tileone}

\end{document}
```

Only three lines were added:

- `\sbox{\tileone}{`
- `}`
- `\usebox{\tileone}`

There is no `missing \endgroup` that is readily apparent here.  Can anyone offer and explanation? or a fix/work-around?

I looked at these other questions, but neither had a relevant answer:

- [Error !Missing \endgroup inserted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/561952/error-missing-endgroup-inserted).  This one had a table and the answer concerned a `table` feature
- [Missing $ inserted, Missing \endgroup inserted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531996/missing-inserted-missing-endgroup-inserted).  This one concerned math mode and the answer specifically wrapped `\neq` in `$$`.

Comment: the first error is Improper prevdepth, as often the case, if you scroll past the first error, later error messages are spurious

Comment: note that apart from the error you have a spurious space at the start and end of the sbox from the ends of line after `{` and after `\end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: The `tikz` option to `standalone` is not a shorthand for “also load Ti*k*Z”. If you use the class for making a single standalone picture, avoid the option and add explicitly `\usepackage{tikz}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is

```
! Improper \prevdepth.
```

You only see the spurious missing `\endgroup` error if you scroll past this.

The Improper prevdepth error means that you are using vertical mode material in the horizontal sbox. this is due to a `\newpage` that apparently `standalone` attaches to `tikzpicture` . As you can not have a new page in an sbox it suffices just to disable that command locally.

```
%\documentclass{article}\usepackage{tikz}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

 
\begin{document}

\newsavebox{\tileone}
\sbox{\tileone}{\let\newpage\relax
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
    \clip (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
    \begin{scope}[dashed,blue]
        \draw plot (\x,\x-1);
        \draw plot (\x,\x+1);
        \draw plot (\x,-\x+1);
        \draw plot (\x,-\x+3);
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\usebox{\tileone}

\end{document}
```